# How to use Drake with deep reinforcement learning

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, simulation, robotics, drake

Does drake have a pipeline/platform with which I can implement deep reinforcement learning algorithms?

Answer (score 0):

Drake is frequently used as an environment in open-source deep RL frameworks; it should plug in nicely.  You can find some examples by searching the web, and would welcome more public examples.

(We will likely make a tutorial for it on the main drake site once we move the tutorials to their own repo so that they can have additional dependencies).